# Map children of React element after the child has rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `react-markdown` which expects a string for its child.

```
<ReactMarkdown>my string</ReactMarkdown>
```

This will transform `my string` into `<p>my string</p>`.

Now I want to do some transformation of the child of the `p` element, which is to recursively check if the child of the current node is a string, and if so, run a regex to replace certain patterns with an React component.

If I run

```
let md = <ReactMarkdown>my string</ReactMarkdown>;
return React.cloneElement(md, { 
    children: React.Children.map(md.props.children, child => <MyWrapper>{child}</MyWrapper>)
});
```

it applies `<MyWrapper>` to `my string` rather than to `<p>my string</p>`.  Since `<ReactMarkdown>` expects a string child, it throws an error.

How can I wrap the children of the rendered child elements rather than the pre-rendered children?

Comment: Since the library only accepts a string which they then break down, you can't provide your own component. You can pass on a css class to control it. If you want to transform the text, you can do it before providing the string to `ReactMarkdown`. Are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the pattern `/:someStr:/g` with a `<CustomElement />` in the entire tree produced by `<ReactMarkdown>`.  I search recursively through the children of the element to find text nodes, and then apply the regex replacement to it.

Comment: Do you control the component that renders `ReactMarkdown`? If so, you can wrap it with your own component that will transform the text before passing it on.